# Read named pipe as output to echoing to a pipe

Tags: linux, pipe

I've created a few named pipes for a few client programs such as cec so I only need to make the connection once in the background and just pipe in commands. Most of the time I don't need to read the output but I need to sometimes and would like to find some way. 
What I have setup

```
sudo mkfifo /dev/cecIn
sudo chmod 666 /dev/cecIn
tailf /dev/null > /dev/cecIn #keep pipe open

sudo mkfifo /dev/cecOut
sudo chmod 666 /dev/cecOut

cat /dev/cecIn | cec-client -s > /dev/cecOut
```

Sending cec commands in is great and really fast since I keep the connection open. Right now I use `echo as > /dev/cecIn` for example, but if I want the output from `echo tx 40:8f > /dev/cecIn #power status` to return I can't find a clean way. I can `cat` the out pipe in another window and see it works and I understand where it's not coming to stdout normally and that the processes are separate, but is there a way to run a command/script to process the cecOut pipe that was generated from a cecIn input?

I'm in Debian Jessie if it matters